# Unable to install packages using dotnet add package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, nuget, dotnet-cli

I'm a .NET newbie using VS Code while following an online course on Angular and .NET Core. The course requires the *AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection* package to be installed but I keep getting the following errors when I try install ***any*** package.

- *Unable to resolve <package_name> for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'*
- *Package <package_name> is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project <csproj_path>*

I use the following command to install the package:

```
dotnet add package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Added *PackageReference* manually into the .csproj file then using *dotnet restore* - results in the same error (NU1100)
2. Cleared the NuGet package cache using *dotnet nuget locals all --clear* - results in the same error

It was working before when I tried to install the *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite* package at the beginning of the course and now for some reason I can't  install any package.

Do note that I'm not able to use the NuGet extension as it's not working behind a corporate proxy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue by deleting the *NuGet.Config* file in *C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet* folder then running *dotnet restore*

Running *dotnet restore* created a fresh config file on the folder which i noticed has a different *packageSources* value than the old one.

The old one had *https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/* while the new one had *https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json*

I completely forgot that I have VS 2010 (with nuget) installed which was responsible for the old config file and I did not realize that nuget from the dotnet-cli was also using the same old configurations.

Comment: This was also the fix for a project in VSCode not building as well.

Comment: This also fixes the "error: the local source ... doesn't exist", thank you so much. Without your answer I might've been too scared to remove the whole .nuget directory which of course solved the whole issue.

Comment: Does anyone know what the Linux equivalent to 
```pwsh
C:\Users\[Environment]::UserName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
```
 is?