# Error on build command in .NET Core (no such host is known)

Tags: .net-core, build, command

I'm making a basic console Application in .NET Core and when I try to run the command "dotnet build -c release -r win10-x64" I get this:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  No such host is known.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  No such host is known.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  No such host is known.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  No such host is known.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  No such host is known.
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  No such host is known.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64' from remote source 'http://packagesourc
e/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'. [C:\Users\steve\PlatziCSharp\PlatziCSharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\Users\steve\PlatziCSharp\PlatziCSharp.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64' from remote source 'http://packagesourc
e/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'. [C:\Users\steve\PlatziCSharp\PlatziCSharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\Users\steve\PlatziCSharp\PlatziCSharp.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:08.30## Heading ##
```

It seems that it missing some dependencies, I'm really new on this and I couldn't find any answer online
Anyone can help me how can I install what I'm missing?
In the past I tried to do another .NET Core project but this same error appeared and I drop it, this is so frustrating.

Comment: Any luck? am stuck with the same issue

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785951/unable-to-install-packages-using-dotnet-add-package

Answer (score 0):

1. On **Tools** > **Options...** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **package Sources**,
   add a package source by source **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**
2. On **tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Manager Console** enter **dotnet restore** command.

Answer (score 0):

1. On Tools > Options... > NuGet Package Manager > package Sources, add
   a package source by source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2. Restart Visual studio and reload your solution/project