# I can't install Entity Framework Core in my .NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, package, nuget

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core MVC Project and I can't install Entity Framework Core. I tried to run this command

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
```

in the console and I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\Courses\Udemy\MVCExample> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
  Writing C:\Users\Nicolas\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE0E7.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory' into project 'C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\Courses\Udemy\MVCExample\Udemy.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\Courses\Udemy\MVCExample\Udemy.csproj...
info :   GET http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known.
info :   GET http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known.
info :   GET http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
error: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory' from remote source 'http://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InM
emory'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
error:   No such host is known.
```

Does anyone know what's happening? I can't find a solution to this problem

Comment: are you using some cusom package source instead of nuget? What's http://packagesource ?

Comment: No, I just installed .NET Core 3.1 SDK (v3.1.301) and I'm running the command with Powershell console :(
Should I try to configure the nugget source? How could I do it?

Comment: Please try -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json parameter

Comment: I fixed it!! I found the answer on how to configure the nugget source here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785951/unable-to-install-packages-using-dotnet-add-package
Thanks man for help me!!